# .net core entity framework core migration

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

I have a migration class

```cs
public class  Employee
{

    public int EmpId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Department {get; set;}
    public DateTime DOB {get; set;}
    public string Address{get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
}
```

If I wanted to update the type of `EmpId` datatype to string type. How can I update the existing migration.

I wanted to update my existing migration with simple solution.

Comment: You need to create a new migration for changing the type

Comment: Change your data type to a string and run your migrations again.  Don’t forget to give `EmpId` a max length or entity framework will give it max length.   With that said, it may not be a good idea to do this.

Comment: If the original migration hasn't been deployed yet, you can simply delete it and create a new one with this change added on top of the other one. However, if the original migration already made it to production, you'd have to think about ways of migrating that `int` id to a `string` one.

Comment: Hi rameshsriram, seems no simple solution. The comment above is correct and if you are facing any issue, you can update your question.